# How to Fetch Dynamic URL Path within Next.js File

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I'm trying to find exactly what page the user is on. I'm creating a search bar such that when the user hits enter, they are led to another page with their query. For this, I am using a dynamic path. When the user types "abc" for example and searches it, they get led to a page "localhost:3000/search/abc".

I do this through a dynamic path, where I have a Next.js page rendered called search and a folder inside it called [searchText] which has an index.tsx file. I want to know what searchText is so I can query it against my database. However, I can't use window.location.href even inside a useEffect (useEffect seems to not be working on any of my pages) and using the React-Dom Router just gives me:

> ServerRouter { route: '/search/[searchText]', pathname:
> '/search/[searchText]', query: {}, asPath: '/search/[searchText]',
> isFallback: false,   basePath: '', locale: undefined,   locales:
> undefined,   defaultLocale: undefined,   isReady: false,
> domainLocales: undefined,   isPreview: false,   isLocaleDomain: false
> }

This prevents me from using asPath and actually getting meaningful information.
Does anyone know of any workarounds to this problem?

I tried the window.location.href which didn't work because window was not defined. useEffect is not working at all even when I import it (maybe this has something to do with how my React/TypeScript/Next app is set up) and the router when initialized in /search/[searchText]/index.tsx is unable to return meaningful information as there is nothing of meaning in asPath and query.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this was very stupid. Didn't realize `console.log()` was logging in the console online, not VSCode's console. Most of the time `console.log()` is just logging in VSCode so that was surprising. Everything is working now. Ended up not doing window.location.href because that was returning nothing and just using `location.href` which is working properly.